# Prevent Chrome from caching specific fields

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, caching

I have a web application with a login page with a "user name" and "password" fields.
When I ask Google Chrome to cache the user name and the password it's doing so not only for the login page, but for every "user name" and "password" fields in any web page of the application, which is wrong.

Is there a way to prevent Chrome from caching a field value for a specific field?
I read about adding the "autocomplete="off" attribute to the field in the HTML, but it's not working.
I do wish to keep the ability to cache the fields values for the login page.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the autocomplete on the form itself should work:

```
<form autocomplete="off">
```